# Has elisp some object inspector?

Tags: elisp

Do you know about some elisp object inspector? I want object tree view similar to ones in javascript consoles in browsers.

Object:

```
(list (list "foo" "bar" "baz") "some" "thing")
```

Inspector:

```
list
|
+- list
|  |
|  +- "foo"
|  |
|  +- "bar"
|  |
|  +- "baz"
|
+- "some"
|
+- "thing"
```

It will be awesome with some folding of tree nodes.

Comment: Similar in what ways? The question seems too broad/vague, IMO. Can you be more precise in what you're asking?

Comment: It's clear what he wants if you have used any reasonable debugger or development system outside of emacs. He provided a mock-up of the tree inspector too. The ability to browse lists and their components in a hierarchical tree. Objects would have their values and docstring display in a hover (a more dynamic version of C-h v), functions possibly a link to their documentation, sublists could be expanded, etc.